# How to get Total number of Rows from a query with also all column

Tags: sql

I have this simple query, I want to retrieve all the data that select statement is selecting now (rightly), plus I want to get total rows number using the same query how can I do this. How do I add total rows query with below query?

```
SELECT
tblTaxingSchemeDetails.TaxSchemeDetailsId,
tblTaxingScheme.TaxSchemeId, 
tblTaxingScheme.TaxSchemeName, 
tblTaxingSchemeDetails.TaxType,
TaxName,
tblTaxingSchemeDetails.TaxRate
From tblTaxingScheme INNER JOIN tblTaxingSchemeDetails  
On tblTaxingScheme.TaxSchemeId = tblTaxingSchemeDetails.TaxSchemeId
INNER JOIN tblTaxType 
on tblTaxingSchemeDetails.TaxType = tblTaxType.TaxTypeID
where tblTaxingScheme.TaxSchemeId =5@TaxSchemeId
```

Comment: Show an example of what you expect to see.

Comment: I don't see any C# code here.  In general when you get records from a database in code you end up with a collection of some sort.  In C# you can call `.Count()` on that collection to get the total.  And the collection itself would have the data from the query.  How are you getting the data?  Filling a `DataTable`?  Linq to SQL?  Entity Framework?  Something else?

Comment: What about `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY...)`? Then your last item has a row number that equals the amount of records for that query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last item of this result has a row number that equals the number of records.

```
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() over(tblTaxingSchemeDetails.TaxSchemeDetailsId)as SeqNo,
tblTaxingSchemeDetails.TaxSchemeDetailsId,
tblTaxingScheme.TaxSchemeId, 
tblTaxingScheme.TaxSchemeName, 
tblTaxingSchemeDetails.TaxType,
TaxName,
tblTaxingSchemeDetails.TaxRate
From tblTaxingScheme INNER JOIN tblTaxingSchemeDetails  
On tblTaxingScheme.TaxSchemeId = tblTaxingSchemeDetails.TaxSchemeId
INNER JOIN tblTaxType 
on tblTaxingSchemeDetails.TaxType = tblTaxType.TaxTypeID
where tblTaxingScheme.TaxSchemeId =5@TaxSchemeId
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  * COUNT(*) OVER() AS [Total_Rows] 
FROM table 1 innerjoin table 2

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired result through this Query... Also would remind this query would be take more resource while compare to the normal query...

```
SELECT
COUNT(tblTaxingSchemeDetails.TaxSchemeDetailsId) over(PARTITION BY tblTaxingScheme.TaxSchemeId)     as h,
tblTaxingSchemeDetails.TaxSchemeDetailsId,
tblTaxingScheme.TaxSchemeId, 
tblTaxingScheme.TaxSchemeName, 
tblTaxingSchemeDetails.TaxType,
TaxName,
tblTaxingSchemeDetails.TaxRate
From tblTaxingScheme INNER JOIN tblTaxingSchemeDetails  
On tblTaxingScheme.TaxSchemeId = tblTaxingSchemeDetails.TaxSchemeId
INNER JOIN tblTaxType 
on tblTaxingSchemeDetails.TaxType = tblTaxType.TaxTypeID
where tblTaxingScheme.TaxSchemeId =5@TaxSchemeId
```